# Tan-1 on Numbers

Tags: macos, numbers

Is there a way to do tan-1 using numbers on El Capitan to return an angle?

I have two lengths 1.5 and 2.2 for example. I can do it on a scientific calculator but not on numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The inverse of tan is arctan. This is the atan function in Numbers.

I found this by in the function sidebar choosing Trigonometric and see g what was there.